# Splitting large .vmdk disk roughly 3 TB in size into several small ones

Tags: vmware, esxi, vsphere

As mentioned in the title, I need to split large .vmdk file which contains a Database into several smaller (4) ones. I don't actually need them to work, just need the 4 separate files with roughly the same content (Database entries) inside.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: VMware Workstation allows mounting of virtual disks, create an appropriate sized virtual disk(s), mount all 5 disks and transfer the data from the original disks to the new disks.

Comment: @Ramhound a database is usually one huge file and needs a little bit more than just transfer the data to 5 disks. See my answer for a more clarifying version of what you've written.

Comment: You can use `vmware-vdiskmanager` to split a monolithic virtual disk in split virtual disks.

Comment: @jamesdlin sounds like a perfect answer to me. Why don't you write one up?

Comment: @LPChip Because I don't know how to use `vmware-vdiskmanager` for ESXi.

Answer (score 1):

A .vmdk is a disk image with a filesystem inside.

It is not a database file by itself.

If your guest operating system is Windows, you could do the following:

Create 4 new vmdk files that are the size you want, that when counted togeter at least have 3TB of size, possibly more. So 1TB each for a total of 4TB is an option.

Mount each vmdk file in your OS and convert each into a dynamic disk. Then create one partition that spans all 4 disks to create a new 4TB partition spanning 4 disks.

Now, copy the database to the new partition.

Another option is to use something like 7zip or winrar to create an archive containing the 3TB vmdk file, and split it into 4 volumes of say... 800GB each. That should create 3x 800GB and 1x 600GB files.

The database cannot be accessed when in zipped state, but after archiving, the vmdk of 3TB is available again and can then be accessed normally.